# How to prove by natural deduction?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Hi I am new to Mathematical Logic and recently I self-tutored on natural deduction.
I have learned natural deduction rules like:

- Rule for $\wedge$-formula.
- Rule for $\rightarrow$-formula.
- Rule for $\bot$ and RAA.

Can anyone help me in proving this formula?

$$(S\rightarrow \neg R) \rightarrow ( S\rightarrow R)$$

By natural deduction using the above rules or any related rules to learn more.

Comment: Have you checked it with truth table ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I want proof by natural deduction not by truth table can you do that and help

Answer (score 2):

You should check it with truth table as @MauroALLEGRANZA commented. This formula is not tautology (that is, it is not true in any interpretation). One may prove only a tautology (well, in consistent logic). So, there is no natural deduction proof of this formula.